# Selecting nearest features based off another layer and sum using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a polygon layer ("Population2018") where the population is divided into 1km2 squares. I have calculated a field for this layer for the total volume of water consumed per day (m3/day) by the population of that square. I have another point layer ("Water Plants") showing locations of water production plants and the total volume of water they produce in one day (m3/day). I am trying to figure out how I could select squares from the Population2018 layer that are nearest to the Water Plants location and match the total consumed water to the produced water by the water plants. Say a plant produces 800m3/day water and the three squares around it equal 800m3/day in their water consumption, how would I select these three squares. Essentially, how many residents can the water plants provide water for. I have also made a field for the Water Plants layer of the number of people for which water can be provided per day.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.8.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to reconcile matching values as depicted below.  You need a rule set to choose which two populated cells that sum up to the water plants 1000m3/day you are going to use.

[image: Example]

As another example of how you need to define a rule set is this:

[image: Example 2]

You have 2 cells that add up to 1000m3/day but their centroid total distance is 2.3km but you have 1 cell which is 2km which matches the output of your water plant and is not adjacent but its total centroid distance is nearer.

I suspect I could find a few more scenarios, but until you explain how you are to deal with these in your question it is difficult for others to offer up a solution.